# How to prevent slick slider stopping when it is clicked several times?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, slick.js

I have created a slider with some image items that is infinitely scrolling with autoplay.
I've disabled pause on hover and i want to prevent every single event that would trigger it to stop.

One specific thing with that is when I'm clicking on it several times, then it stops and i can drag it. I don't want this behaviour and i thing I've done everything to prevent it. I want it to be unstoppable

Those are mine Slick Carousel setting:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
 $('.clients-slider').slick({
 infinite: false,
 slidesToShow: 6,
 slidesToScroll: 1,
 autoplay: true,
 speed: 5000,
 draggable: false,
 swipe: false,
 swipeToSlide: false,
 centerMode: false,
 arrows: false,
 dots: false,
 focusOnSelect: false,
 accessibility: false,
 touchMove: false,
 pauseOnHover: false,
 pauseOnFocus: false,
 pauseOnSwipe: false, 
 cssEase: 'linear',
responsive: [
  {
    breakpoint: 1366,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 4
    }
  },
  {
    breakpoint: 768,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 3
    }
  }
],
});
});
```

Here is my html/php code (I'm doing it in wordpress):

```
<section class="clients" id="clients">
<h2 class="offer-head" style="max-width: 1300px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"><?php echo $partnerzy; ?></h2>
<div class="clients-slider" pause-on-hover="false" draggable="false">
    <?php if( have_rows('slajder_partnerzy') ): ?>
        <?php while( have_rows('slajder_partnerzy') ): the_row(); ?>
            <img  class="clients-slide-single" src="<?php echo get_sub_field('partner_logo'); ?>" alt="logo-client" />
        <?php endwhile ?>
    <?php endif ?>    
</div>
```

Can anyone relate on this? Of course I'm properly importing jquery and slick carousel library.

Comment: you want `infinite: false` to be `infinite: true` probably

Comment: This gives me no change. Working exactly the same with true or false on this attribute

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to work, with `infinite:true`

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.clients-slider').slick({
    infinite: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,

    slidesToShow: 6,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    speed: 1000,
    delay: 1000,
    draggable: false,
    swipe: false,
    swipeToSlide: false,
    centerMode: false,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    focusOnSelect: false,
    accessibility: false,
    touchMove: false,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    pauseOnFocus: false,
    pauseOnSwipe: false,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 1366,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      }
    ],
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>


Here is my html/php code (I'm doing it in wordpress):

<section class="clients" id="clients">
  <h2 class="offer-head" style="max-width: 1300px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
    <?php echo $partnerzy; ?>
  </h2>
  <div class="clients-slider" pause-on-hover="false" draggable="false">
    <?php if( have_rows('slajder_partnerzy') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('slajder_partnerzy') ): the_row(); ?>
<img class="clients-slide-single" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/200" alt="logo-client" />    
    <img class="clients-slide-single" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="logo-client" />

    <img class="clients-slide-single" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="logo-client" />
    <?php endwhile ?>
    <?php endif ?>
  </div>
```